# Form fields not being displayed Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I am still learning Django. I have been looking at various tutorials but I am struggling with forms on django framework. 
The problem is that I am unable to display the form field for email on the base.html page. It is basically a subscription form. I am still new to django. This is what I have made till now.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class SubscribeModel(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from models import SubscribeModel

class SubscribeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=SubscribeModel
```

views.py

```
def loadform(request):
    form = SubscribeForm()
    return render_to_response('base.html', {'form': form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

base.html

```
<html>
 ...
 <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
   <input type="submit" value="Subscribe"></ul>
 </form>
 ...
</html>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', 'chsite.blog.views.index'),
url(r'^$', 'chsite.blog.views.loadform'),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: If you want a email field, just use the Django's one: `email = models.EmailField()`

Comment: @sgmart I changed to that also. Still the field is not showing up. Could it be something wrong with urls.py file? I am editing the answer and also mentioning urls.py file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are edited the question, I can see two url(---) reffenceced to the same url. Hence Django will loadd the first one. It means you never load the loadform view. So try removing the line:

```
url(r'^$', 'chsite.blog.views.index'),
```

or edit the actual tuple for the loadform for instance:

```
url(r'^suscribe/$', 'chsite.blog.views.loadform'),
```

and go to your browser at 127.0.0.1:8000/suscribe/ url.

Comment: Oh this is perfect. But what if I want to display two views on same HTML page? What do i need to do for that? For example, I have index class and loadform class and I want both to render on base.html.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define different url patterns as your first two are identical. URL processing stops at first hit, in your case uses index view.